# diff.getYears() returns 0. Calculating Age from LocalDate birth date

Tags: java

```
SimpleDateFormat format3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

String birthDate = format3.format(date);

try {
    age = format3.parse(birthDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if(age != null)
c.setTime(age);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date2 = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
LocalDate l1 = LocalDate.of(year,month,date2);
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
Period diff = Period.between(l1,now);
Integer age = diff.getYears();
String ageString = age.toString();
```

Comment: what's `date`? For me it works.

Comment: My very wild guess would be that you get an Exception when trying to parse the date in `age = format3.parse(birthDate);` and therefor your `Calendar c` will be the current date/time. Check your logs for an Exception message and better yet: Don't just continue with your program if parsing the date fails, it's almost always better to have `throw new RuntimeException(e);` in your catch block to have your program end when an error happens rather than just continuing despite an error and acting like nothing happened.

Comment: Why not use `LocalDate.parse(birthDate)` instead? Much easier (and less error-prone) than involving `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach using [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). It is not only shorter, but also less error-prone.

```java
String inputDate = "1990/01/21";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

LocalDate age = LocalDate.parse(inputDate, formatter);
Period diff = Period.between(age, LocalDate.now()); // outputs: 31 years
```

Comment: Aaah, hyphens not slashes. My mistake.

Comment: You may want to adjust your comment on your final statement.